Router have 2 ip address private ip and public ip (PPPoE). How to point domain to setup a homeserver
I bought a domain from Hostinger. Eg:homelab-server.site
I check my router having 2 ip address:

public ip: A (showing in browser)
private ip: B (showing in router from PPPoe section)

I try to open some port from my computer. I can access my website only from B ip address. Eg: B:80, B:3000
Now I want to point my domain from Hostinger to my ip to check my webserver. But pointing to both A and B are not working.
Anyone can help me to config in my case?

Is your public IP a CG-NAT address? If so, then you are screwed

It should always point to your public IP A. Now that doesnt mean things will work, or will work immediately. If you are behind CG-NAT as pointed out above, it wont work. Secondly, when you point your domain to an IP, this gets listed in a DNS server. This system then needs to propagate to ALL DNS servers. This can take upto 24h. And lastly, sometimes you cant connect to your public IP (A) from inside your own network (B) because of something called NAT hairpinning. So be sure to test from outside network B as well !

Sure, that is a CG-NAT IP. I requested to my IPS to serve real IP address. After I added new IP. The DNS DNS checker still can't find my domain. Maybe due to propagation time. I don't know if it will be long :(

When you go to something like whatismyip.com is that showing your new "real" (routable) IP address?   Also, can I assume homelab-server.site is made up?  (That domain has not been registered)
